# How does the garbage collector work in PHP

Tags: php, garbage-collection, foreach, redhat

I have a PHP script that has a large array of people, it grabs their details from an external resource via SOAP, modifies the data and sends it back. Due to the size of the details I upped PHP's memory to 128MB. After about 4 hours of running (It will probably take 4 days to run) it ran out of memory. Heres the basics of what it does:

```
$people = getPeople();
foreach ($people as $person) {
    $data = get_personal_data();
    if ($data == "blah") {
        importToPerson("blah", $person);
    } else {
        importToPerson("else", $person);
    }
}
```

After it ran out of memory and crashed I decided to initialise $data before the `foreach` loop and according to `top`, memory usage for the process hasn't risen above 7.8% and it's been running for 12 hours.

So my question is, does PHP not run a garbage collector on variables initialised inside the loop even if reused? Is the system reclaiming the memory and PHP hasn't marked it as usable yet and will eventually crash again (I've upped it to 256MB now so I've changed 2 things and not sure which has fixed it, I could probably change my script back to answer this but don't want to wait another 12 hours for it to crash to figure out)?

I'm not using the Zend framework so the other question like this I don't think is relevant.

EDIT: I don't actually have an issue with the script or what it's doing. At the moment, as far as all system reporting is concerned I don't have any issues. This question is about the garbage collector and how / when it reclaims resources in a  foreach loop and / or how the system reports on memory usage of a php process.

Comment: I'm interested in hearing why this has been down-voted twice now...

Comment: What happens in `importToPerson()`?

Comment: Shouldn't `if ($data = "blah") {` be `if ($data == "blah") {`?

Comment: until the script finishes, php's garbage collector should leave it alone, you need to manage the memory usage inside the script.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa Don't worry about the script above, it is just the basics to get across that I was initialising a variable inside the foreach loop and had memory issues, initialising outside the foreach loop seems to have stopped the issue but without knowing more about the way the garbage collector works I can't be sure.

Comment: @Dagon well from what I'm seeing I seem to have managed the memory usage but I don't know enough about how PHP and the system reclaims the memory to be certain.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this manpage: http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

Comment: @Dagon that is not true.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

Comment: if your script is running out of memory, chances are something in the script is creating new objects or scalars which are never being nulled or re-used for something else. that, or you have an old version of PHP running. you can use XDebug to see where the problem lies.

Comment: http://derickrethans.nl/xdebug-and-tracing-memory-usage.html

Comment: @dqhendricks I did look through that and tried to get it to work but couldn't for some reason (maybe due to config, I did enable it so it wasn't that). I also thought it might cause more issues than solves and initialising variables outside the loop seems to have fixed it, which I thought was odd not knowing enough about the garbage collector.

Comment: @dqhendricks It was running out of memory but I fixed it by initialising outside the loop. This isn't really a "help, its not working" question more of a "why did this work" question.

Comment: @Rudiger The link I posted explains how php gc works, so I figured it would be helpful. As to why it worked, it shouldn't, unless there is something you are not showing us. which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @dqhendricks 5.2.17 It's a custom one from iuscommunity.org (sys admin did it, don't know much about it) because we need to use mcrypt. I know it probably shouldn't work, hence the question because from all the reporting I can do at the moment, it is working.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the insides of PHP's VM, but from my experience, it doesn't garbage collect whilst your page is running. This is because it throws away everything your page created when it finishes.

Most of the time, when a page runs out of memory and the limit is pretty high (and 128Mb isn't high), there is an algorithm problem. Many PHP programmers assemble a structure of data, then pass it to the next step which iterates over the structure, usually creating another one. Lather, rinse, repeat. Unfortunately, this approach is a big memory hog and you end up creating multiple copies of your data in memory. Two of the really big changes in PHP 5 was that objects are reference counted, not copied, and the entire string subsystem was made much much faster. But it's still a problem.

To minimise memory use, you would look at re-structuring your algorithm so it can work with one piece of data from start to finish. Then you get the next and start again. Best case scenario is that you don't ever have the entire dataset in memory. For a database-backed website, this would mean processing a row of data from a database query all the way to presentation before getting the next. Of course, this approach isn't always possible and the script just has to keep a huge wodge of data in memory.

That said, you can do this memory-saving approach for part of the data. The trick is that you explicitly `unset()` a key variable or two at the end of the loop. This *should* reclaim the space. The other "best-practice" trick is to shift out of the loop data manipulation that doesn't need to be in the loop. As you seem to have discovered.

I've run PHP scripts that need upwards of 1Gb of memory. You can set the memory limit per script, actually, with `ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');`

Comment: PHP 5.3 added a "real" garbage collector. It's still imperfect, but it's an improvement over what you're describing.

Comment: It's actually being run on the command line. Although I did think of doing a row each time (rather than all rows and iterating through the returned array) I felt that the extra database queries would negate any benefit from it.

Comment: It's plausible to have an enormous loop to process each row, but you can easily have resource issues trying to execute a new query when you're still in the middle of fetching the results of the previous. Also, sometimes it's faster to do lots of little SQL queries than fewer heavier ones.

Comment: The automatic triggers for PHP cycle garbage collector are not clever so if you do something that can cause big objects referring each other with no reference from anywhere, you should call `gc_collect_cycles()` after possibly leaking memory (http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php). That causes some extra CPU usage but it will reduce the memory usage. Otherwise PHP could clean up the garbage much later in the future and in the mean time, your memory usage is much higher than expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)() to see what going on? Could put it inside of the loop to see the behavior in memory allocation.
Have you tried looking at the system monitor or whatever to see how much memory php is using during that process?

Comment: Don't want to modify the script atm as we would have to start it again from scratch (already a day down the drain). Top is the system monitor and memory usage hasn't risen above 7.8% so in theory no more memory allocations and the script shouldn't run out of memory.

Comment: And you couldn't run another script with these modifications with a limit on the number iterations? i.e. I'm not completely sure what you are doing.

Comment: The script is actually quite process intensive as it does a lot of SOAP requests / database manipulation. If I can't get an answer I will investigate a bit later but it will take probably a day of changing the script, running it for an hour or so, monitoring memory allocations, rinse and repeating. Was hoping for someone more knowledgable than myself on the PHP garbage collector to give some insight.